# Not able to search through character varying[] array column

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

My postgres database table has a column location which is character `varying[]`. In my nestjs entity of the table I have following for the location column-

```
 @Column("character varying",{array:true})
    location: string[];
```

What I am trying to do is search the rows having passed parameter as locations.
This is the raw query which is giving me appropriate results-

```
select * from blogs where language @> '{"Spanish","English"}'
```

In my nestjs service, how can I achieve the above query?
I tried doing this-

```
return await this.blogsRepo.find({
  where: [
    {
      location: Any(body.locations)
    }
  ]
})
```

`body.locations` is an array like this-

```
body.locations = ["Spanish","English"]
```

The above typeorm solution gives me following error-

> 'could not find array type for data type character varying[]'

What could be the possible solution for this? I will love a typeorm solution as I have kept raw query execution as my last option.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the typeorm documentations, there is no way/ built in typeorm operator equivalent to `@>` operator.

So the only way to achieve what I wanted is to generate an entire query and then execute it using `Repository.query()` method.

Seems to work so far!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
await this.blogsRepo.find({
  where: `${body.locations} = ANY (location)`,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit late but for those who came across this question,
you can achieve this by the `Raw` operator of Typeorm:

```
import { Raw } from 'typeorm';
```

---

- If the field is a `character varying` field, which an example value would be like:

```
{value1, value2, value3}
```

You could do this:

```
const searchKey = 'value3'

sampleRepo.find({
   where: {
      columnName: Raw((alias) => ` '${searchKey}' = ANY (${alias})`),
   }
})
```

---

- And if it is a `jsonb` field, which the example value would be like:

```
[{key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}, {key1: 'value21', key2: 'value22'}])
```

You could do this:

```
const searchKey = 'value1'

sampleRepo.find({
   where: {
      columnName: Raw((alias) => ` ${alias} @> '[{"key1": "${searchKey}"}]'`)
   }
})
```